# Download pictures and wait for each one iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, queue, task

I'm trying to put some images into an array but the images are not in the right order its showing image 3 where 1 should be things like that.

Below is my code i have tried to add a dispatch in. I just need it to wait until each one is done before moving on.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

    if post.imageUrl1 != nil {
        group.enter()
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl1!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: post.imageUrl1!)
            storageRef.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.cars.append(pic!)
            }
        }
         group.leave()
    }
    if post.imageUrl2 != nil {
        group.enter()
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl2!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: post.imageUrl2!)
            storageRef.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.cars.append(pic!)
            }
        }
         group.leave()
    }
    if post.imageUrl3 != nil {
        group.enter()
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl3!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: post.imageUrl3!)
            storageRef.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.cars.append(pic!)
            }
        }
         group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Tony: Got the pics in order")
    }
```

Comment: I think group.leave() should be added right after each cars.append statement not outside. Though there is a simpler way of achieving with the use of completion handlers.

Comment: Ill give this a go

Comment: this didn't seem to work still the same problem Thanks for the advice anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your image 3 is being downloaded much faster than image 1, thus populated to the array before.

instead of appending to the array. define the array with 3 nil images at first, and replace yourArray[0] with pic 1, yourArray[1] with pic 2 and yourArray[2] with picture 3. You will always get the right order this way.

PS: consider caching your images so that you dont download them each time! (SDWebImage is a perfect library)

Comment: I have it caching images already but it doesn't seem to put them in an array I can access. I am trying to access the images that are in a collection view so when i tap on it I can have it show full screen in a new controller. I asked about getting the cached images into an array but nobody answers. Thanks for the advice